# Does the python code executes in order

Tags: python, subprocess, diff

I am creating a file and then doing diff on it.

I want to do diff on the file which iscreated in previous step but i get the error that file dont exist .

This is my code

```
os.popen("mysqldump --login-path=server1_mysql -e --opt --skip-lock-tables  --skip-extended-insert -c %s > %s.sql" % (database, filename))
os.popen("diff %s %s > %s" % (weekly, filename, filename+".PATCH"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.popen()` has been [deprecated since version 2.6](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=popen#os.popen). However, to get your code working, you should wait for the first process to finish (and the output file to be created) before starting the second.

The exit status of the first command is available as the return value of the `close()` method of the file object returned, so you can check that before continuing, i.e.:

```
pipe = os.popen("mysqldump --login-path=server1_mysql -e --opt "
                "--skip-lock-tables  --skip-extended-insert -c %s > %s.sql" % 
                (database, filename))
if pipe.close() is None:  # no errors?
    os.popen("diff %s %s > %s" % (weekly, filename, filename+".PATCH"))
```

Comment: Thanks dude , only ur code works. That may not be perfect but that worked

Comment: Glad to hear that, however you really should convert your code at some point to use `subprocess.call()` -- it's definitely better and usually relatively easier to use.

Answer (score 5):

[`os.popen` is deprecated. Use the subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). `subprocess.call` will block the main process until the command is finished. You should inspect the returncode, `retval`, in case there was an error while executing the `mysqldump` command. In that case, you can not continue with the `diff`:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
with open("{f}.sql".format(f=filename), 'w') as fout:
    retval = subprocess.call(
        shlex.split(
            """mysqldump --login-path=server1_mysql -e --opt --skip-lock-tables
            --skip-extended-insert -c %s""" % (database, )),
        stdout=fout)

if not retval == 0:
    raise Exception('Error executing command: {r}'.format(r=retval))
else:
    with open("{f}.PATCH".format(f=filename), 'w') as fout:
        retval = subprocess.call(
            shlex.split("diff {w} {f}".format(w=weekly, f=filename)),
            stdout=fout)
```

Comment: In this case, there's nothing to `communicate` so it's simpler to just call `proc.wait()`.  But in general, yes (upvoted).

Comment: Oh, one other thing I noticed just now: using `shlex.split` is usually good but in this case the string expects the shell to do a redirect, so you'd need `shell=True` and not want to split the string.  Or (more secure than attempting to quote shell metacharacters), open the output file in Python and pass it as `stdout=` in the subprocess invocation.

Comment: is the above syntax correct , i am getting syntax error. i am getting `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ` that filename does not exist , mysql dump will create it, i don't know how u did it

Comment: @user22: Sorry, I forget to open the files in write mode. The post is now updated.

Comment: I get the same error no such file or directory , also you have syntax error `shlex.split("diff {w} {f}".format(w=weekly, f=filename)
                        stdout=fout))` , it should be  `(shlex.split("diff {w} {f}".format(w=weekly, f=daily_filename)),stdout=fout)`

Answer (score 0):

A super simple way is to use busy waiting:

```
os.popen("mysqldump --login-path=server1_mysql -e --opt --skip-lock-tables  --skip-extended-insert -c %s > %s.sql" % (database, filename))
while not os.path.isfile(filename):
    sleep(0.05) # or some other interval
os.popen("diff %s %s > %s" % (weekly, filename, filename+".PATCH"))
```

**EDIT:**

Use with care, leaves a race condition because the condition that is being checked is only that the file *exists*, not the the previous process is finished writing.

Comment: Busy waiting *is* simple, but unnecessary; and this leaves in a race condition: the diff may start up around the time mysqldump has started but before mysqldump has finished.

Comment: True enough, this was probably a little _too_ simple. I still think learning simple (_old school_ if you like) solutions like busy waiting is a useful thing, and in some cases it's still necessary. But I agree that it's suboptimal in this case.