# How can I make sure OS commands run synchronously within Python?

Tags: python, operating-system, command, synchronous, os.system

I have a python script to rebuild an haproxy configuration and then restart haproxy..  The only problem is that when I run the script from cron, sometimes haproxy gets restarted before the new configuration is in place.

When I run the script from the command line this doesn't happen.

I've tried adding a time.sleep() to the script to have it wait, but sometimes this still happens.  Here's the relevant code:

```
command = "/home/adam/bin/genproxy.sh"
os.system(command)
os.system("cp /home/adam/bin/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/")
time.sleep(2)
os.system("sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy restart")
```

How can I make sure the restart waits until the copy completes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17651370/661195 Does this help ?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this should do it.

```
commands = [ ... ]
for command in commands:
    if os.system(command) == 0:
        # Check for failure and wait
        continue
    else:
        print "ERROR"
        break
```